# Any possible way to read RAID health status within Xenserver without rebooting?

Tags: raid, xenserver

I have an Asus motherboard with PIKE card (based on LSI chipset I believe) running Xenserver 6.5.  Is there any way to see the RAID status within the virtual host without the need to reboot and enter the configuration utility?

All I need to know is "Good/Rebuilding/Degraded/Failed" status.

lspci shows the hardware as:

```
0e:00.0 SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS1068E PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS (rev 08)
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI the 1068E is on the Xenserver HCL: http://hcl.xensource.com/storagecontrollers/?storagecontrollersupport__version=5&vendor=116&features=8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) There are two different utilities for managing LSI SAS controllers: mpt-status (opensource) and lsiutil (proprietary). Both are described at http://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/LSIFusionMPT page.

2) It seems that mpt-status should be enough for your needs. It depends on **mptctl** kernel module.

3) XenServer 6.5 is based on CentOS 5. **mpt-status** packages for CentOS 5 can be found here: http://sven.stormbind.net/mpt-status-rhel/

Comment: mpt-status worked perfectly! Thanks!